# airflow cannot find module from imported file

Tags: python, airflow

I have a directory structure like this:

```
dags/
├── airflow_sched.py
├── backend
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── src
│       ├── buffer.py
│       ├── config
│       │   ├── config.py
        |-- stage.py
```

`airflow_sched.py` is where my dag definition file is:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pendulum
from airflow.decorators import dag
from backend.src.stage import stage_data

@dag(
dag_id = "data-sync",
schedule_interval = "1 * * * *",
start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 3, 8, tz="Asia/Hong_Kong"),
catchup=False,
dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20),
)
def Pipeline():
    a = stage_data()
```

The main take of the code above is the `from backend.src.stage import stage_data` it works fine , but in my `stage.py` file there is the config import.

```
from config import config
```

When issuing `airflow dags list-import-errors` I get this:

```
filepath                           | error                                                               
===================================+=====================================================================
/opt/airflow/dags/airflow_sched.py | Traceback (most recent call last):                                  
                                   |   File "/opt/airflow/dags/airflow_sched.py", line 4, in <module>    
                                   |     from backend.src.stage import stage_data                        
                                   |   File "/opt/airflow/dags/backend/src/stage.py", line 5, in <module>
                                   |     from config import config                                       
                                   | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

what is wrong with my import here ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick note regarding the `dags` directory:

- If there are no dags in the `backend` directory then it might be best to move that outside of the `dags/` directory or make sure it's added to a `.airflowignore` file.
- You can add all directories in the `AIRFLOW_HOME` directory to the `PYTHONPATH` by adding the following to the Dockerfile or the local environment, depending on how Airflow is being run. This command will append all directories to the `PYTHONPATH` ENV variable and allow direct imports in your scripts.

`ENV PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH:+${PYTHONPATH}:}${AIRFLOW_HOME}`